# Definition of TFP in Acemoglu & Restrepo Ecta Forthcoming

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

The production structure in the paper: $$y=\left(\frac{1}{M} \int_{\mathcal{T}}(M \cdot y(x))^{\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda}} \cdot d x\right)^{\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}}$$, where $$y(x)=A_{k} \cdot \psi_{k}(x) \cdot k(x)+\sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} A_{g} \cdot \psi_{g}(x) \cdot \ell_{g}(x)$$.

The total labor is supplied inelastically and the capital is produced using final good with a constant mc $1/q(x)$. They rewrite this production structure into $$y=\left(1-A_{k}^{\lambda-1} \cdot \Gamma_{k}\right)^{\frac{\lambda}{1-\lambda}} \cdot\left(\sum_{g \in \mathcal{G}} \Gamma_{g}^{\frac{1}{\lambda}} \cdot\left(A_{g} \cdot \ell_{g}\right)^{\frac{\lambda-1}{\lambda}}\right)^{\frac{\lambda}{\lambda-1}}$$, where  $\Gamma_{g}(\boldsymbol{w}, \Psi)=\frac{1}{M} \int_{\mathcal{T}_{g}} \psi_{g}(x)^{\lambda-1} \cdot d x$ , $\Gamma_{k}(\boldsymbol{w}, \Psi)=\frac{1}{M} \int_{\mathcal{T}_{k}}\left(\psi_{k}(x) \cdot q(x)\right)^{\lambda-1} \cdot d x$. And capital share is $s^{K}=\frac{\frac{1}{M} \int_{\mathcal{T}_{k}} y \cdot p(x)^{1-\lambda} d x}{y}=A_{k}^{\lambda-1} \cdot \Gamma_{k}$.

In their comparative statics they define  $d \ln \operatorname{tfp}=d \ln y-\left.s^{K} \cdot d \ln k\right|_{q}$ wher $k=\int_{\mathcal{T}_{k}} k(x) / q(x) d x$ denotes the total capital stock and $\left.d \ln k\right|_{q}$ denotes changes in the capital stock coming from capital quantities and not prices.

I don't understand where this definition of TFP ($y/k^{s^K}$?) comes from.